# Rsync between systems with different symlink permission semantics (MacOS -> Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, rsync, symlink, macos

I’d like to use rsync for backup of a MacOS machine to an Ubuntu server running ZFS.  The problem is that on MacOS symlinks can have file permissions distinct from their referenced file; whereas on Ubuntu a symlink always reports perms of 777 and in practice behaves as the perms of the target.  On MacOS symlinks receive file perms based on the user’s umask at the time of creation, e.g. 775.  The result is that rsync is perpetually reporting that the permissions differ and wanting to update all of those files.

To add a twist to this, I read in one discussion that ZFS itself actually does support symlink permissions, however this may be incorrect as I can’t find any further references to it, nor does Ubuntu chown have the option to affect it.

I guess my question is if anyone has dealt with this issue before or if there is a way to get rsync to ignore the permissions just for symlinks (I would prefer not to have to modify rsync).  Or maybe I should try to address the issue at the source and “fix” my symlinks on MacOS… I honestly don’t know if any of them are meaningful.  Most of my stuff is media and code for which it certainly doesn’t matter.  Finally I guess I could just write a script to ignore the (itemized) output for those specific files :)

Any suggestions appreciated.  Thanks.

EDIT: I guess I could also just ignore all permissions with `--no-perms`.